# ZF2 + query entity Doctrine2

Tags: zend-framework2, doctrine, entity

I'm doing a query on an entity, but of course I am asked to instantiate doctrine entityManager my serious question:

As instantiate the EntityManager to use in the entity.

Excuse my English, I am using google truth XD, as not meeting ZF2 communities and Doctrine2 in Spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question you want to get the `entityManager` inside your Doctrine entities, right ?

I don't think it's good idea to usee the EntityManager within your Doctrine entities. But for this, you need first to get an instance of the service manager in your entity class.

> By default, the Zend Framework MVC registers an initializer that will inject the ServiceManager instance, which is an implementation of `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface`, into any class implementing `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`

For Doctrine, we have to make the service manager available within the entities. So You have to implement the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` for each entity or simpler create a class which implements `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` and then simply make the entities that need access to the service manager inherit from this class.

Here is a good post on [HOW TO INJECT ZF2 SERVICE MANAGER INTO DOCTRINE ENTITIES](http://michaelthessel.com/injecting-zf2-service-manager-into-doctrine-entities/)

Following this post, you could simply get the `entityManager` within your entity like this :

```
$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
```

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly what I needed and it works.
Now you tell me that is not good practice, so now I have another question.

Where should I go query I am doing, if I can not call EntityManager from the entity. This consultation should go in the driver or where?